# Updating the package in puppet?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, puppet

I am trying to update the already installed package through puppet using ubuntu server .
but is not  updating is not happening.

In puppet manifest file we have included collector package as shown below,

```
if !defined(Package['package name'])
{
        package { 'package name': }
}
else
{
         package { 'package name':
                        ensure => latest,
                        require  => Exec['apt-get update'],
          }
}
```

**can u explain this statement -  if !defined(Package['package name']) or
How to upgrade the package**.Suppose I want to install php while next deployment need to update to latest version...can u share code??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should refrain from using the `defined` function, as it will create parse-dependent behavior, which is not advised.

The piece of puppet code you is probably not doing what you think it does. It enters the `else` branch only if the package is already defined. In that case, you should see an error, as you are re-defining it, and this is forbidden.

This means that the package is *not* defined, and you are defining it with no options. You might want to take a look at the [puppetlabs apt module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt) that can be configured to run `apt-get update` before each package installation, and will generally make things easier to manage (ppa, custom software source, etc.).

Comment: 'if !defined(Package['package name'])
{
        package { 'package name':
                        ensure => latest,
                        require  => Exec['apt-get update'],
          }
}'

Comment: Why would you need to check if the package is already defined ? This will eventually lead to an error, as this function is parse-order dependent. Either you have it defined elsewhere, and you should add the correct `ensure` there, or you don't have defined it, and don't need the check.